# How to order table by Sortvalue in two different way

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by

I have the following table structure.

```
ServiceName ServiceId   SortValue
GHS             1068        0
CSRS            1076        0
HRTR            1030        0
ASAS            1077        0
TTR             11          0
UTYI            3           6
IOKI            1074        9
POLK            1008        8
GHYT            1029        7
NHUY            1078        13
SABF            9           11
ASAE            19          12
HKYL            5           10
CBNG            1009        14
AWAD            1045        15
```

I need to sort the table result in order to its `SortValue` column. But you can see there are multiple rows with the same `SortValue = 0` (this is one and the only behaviour can happen, multiple rows `sortValue` can be 0). As I previously said I need to select the table data order by `SortValue` and 
all `SortValue = 0` data need to sort order by `ServiceName` and others need to order by `SortValue`

According to my above table data, My expected output should be,
[image]

Is it possible to do? I'm really confused with this

Comment: `ORDER BY SortValue, ServiceName` did you try that>

Answer (score 2):

Use two `order by` keys:

```
order by sortValue, serviceName
```

Answer (score 2):

You can order by more than one column and in different directions.

```
...
ORDER BY sortvalue ASC,
         serviceid DESC;
```